Is it possible to avoid `return await` in branches that delegate to a Task with the same return type?
I have an asynchronous method to handle aggregated requests. It basically breaks up the requests into single ones, handled by another method with the same return type, and combines the answers into a single response. In case the aggregate request actually consists only of a single request, I can delegate directly to the second method.
When I do this, since my method is async, I can't return the Task<string> from the other method directly, I need to await it, even though my method doesn't do anything with the result. On the other hand, in the branch that aggregates the responses, I really do need to get the results in order to generate the aggregated response, so I do need to await there.
Having to use return await seems unnatural to me and would seem to deprive the caller of the chance to do any optimizing of its own.
My questions are:

Is it possible/recommended to avoid return await in the branch that delegates to a Task with the same return type? For example by not making the method async, and waiting the Tasks in the second branch using task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()?

Or should I not worry about it because there will never be any noticeable difference in the final result for the caller?


Eventually the result will have to be awaited after all.
This example has been simplified to use simple string operations to demonstrate the idea; in reality my method is significantly more complex.
public async Task<string> ProcessCombinedRequest(List<string> requestList)
{
    if (requestList.Count == 1)
    {
        return await ProcessSingleRequest(requestList[0]);
    }

    // Start all the sub-tasks concurrently
    var taskList = new List<Task<string>>();
    foreach (string request in requestList)
    {
        taskList.Add(ProcessSingleRequest(request));
    }

    // Wait for each of them to finish and get their results
    var aggregatedResponse = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var task in taskList)
    {
        string singleResponse = await task;
        aggregatedResponse.AppendLine(singleResponse);
    }
    return aggregatedResponse.ToString();
}

private async Task<string> ProcessSingleRequest(string request)
{
    // Long running operation
    await Task.Delay(4000);
    return request + " was processed.";
}

Edit: changed Thread.Sleep to await Task.Delay as suggested by @TheodorZoulias to improve the example.

"and waiting the Tasks in the second branch using task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()" - definitively not recommended.

That's what I had read elsewhere but I didn't have any other ideas.

Have you considered using var results = await Task.WhenAll( tasks ); and then go from there? I really wouldn't bother for a special branch for n=1 except if n=1 occurrence outweighs any other by at least one order of magnitude. And even then, I'd first benchmark thoroughly.

The n=1 case is by far the most common.

Eliding async/await has some quirks, especially when it comes to excpetions. So, I wouldn't recommend that light-heartedly. So, if it's not an actual problem I'd just keep the async/await. Maybe there are other things to try that have more effect with less risk.

As a side-note, the ProcessSingleRequest method should give you a compilation warning about an async method that lacks an await operator. Representing the long running operation with await Task.Delay(4000) might be better than Thread.Sleep(4000). Also omitting the Task.WhenAll is wrong. You risk losing track of your tasks, and letting them become fire-and-forget.

"Having to use return await seems unnatural to me and would seem to deprive the caller of the chance to do any optimizing of its own." - can you please elaborate why have you come to such conclusion?

Using return await means that my method actively waits for a result before returning. If I return a hot task instead, the caller can schedule it with its other work and wait for the result at the last possible moment.

@Christopher "Using return await means that my method actively waits for a result before returning." -- Actively waiting is an oxymoron. Waiting is passive. Your method is doing nothing while awaiting.

Yes, but there are caveats and nuances. You can use a non-async method:
public Task<string> ProcessCombinedRequest(List<string> requestList)
{
    // TODO: consider ternary conditional or switch expression, lambda, etc
    // TODO: consider the empty list case?
    if (requestList.Count == 1)
    {
        return ProcessSingleRequest(requestList[0]);
    }
    return ProcessCombinedRequestMulti(requestList);
}
private async Task<string> ProcessCombinedRequestMulti(List<string> requestList)
{
    // Start all the sub-tasks concurrently
    var taskList = new List<Task<string>>();
    // .. etc as before
}

This removes a layer of state-machine overhead, but importantly it also changes the behaviour in the case of exceptions - for example, if requestList turns out to be null, or some other random error happens - instead of returning a faulted Task<string>, your method may throw - and in either case, the observed stacktrace may be subtly different.
If you're confident that there is no risk of this (perhaps with some Debug.Assert checks etc), and the non-async version is likely to be very common, and the performance matters: this is something you can certainly consider. However, if you're not confident of the impact: maybe just don't worry about it...
To give a concrete example of this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ea9d53e694671ca8c70d61eb1df8779959045af6/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/src/Hybrid/HybridCache.cs#L74-L82

Quickly, concisely and well answered! I left out the edge case of empty list to keep things simple, but in fact it is actually included in the foreach, which here synchronously returns an empty string ;-).

@ChristopherHamkins in the orignal code: yes, synchronous, but after spinning up half of the async machinery (the state machine), and a StringBuilder ;p Short-circuiting before you get into an async block saves quite a few moving parts. If you're a library author and this method gets called lots (perhaps inside loops), then: worth optimizing; if you are an application author, and this is (for example) once per request, or once per UI screen change or button click: probably not worth caring about
